# problem with JSF 2.0 login + session scope handling

Tags: session, logging, jsf-2

I'm having a problem handling login in JSF 2.0. I dont really know if I'm going in the right direction. I want to be specific so i will point out how my application works

1. login page with a session scoped
       bean.
2. after a proper login the user
           is redirected to the next page with
           another session scoped bean
3. the
           second bean gets the login and
           password Strings from the firs bean
           for further use with a database

my question is do I create two sessions for the user? If so how can i kill the first session. If its not the best way to manage login please correct me. Thank You in advance

here is a simplyfied example

LOGIN BEAN

```
package main;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@SessionScoped

@ManagedBean(name="loginBean")

public class loginBean implements Serializable
{
    private String login;
    private String password;

    public loginBean()
    {

    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String login() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        SQL sql = new SQL(); //class connecting do database
        if( sql.login(this.login, this.password) == true )
        {
            return "yes"; 
        }
        else
        {
            return "no";
        }
    }

}
```

LOGIN PAGE login.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <div id="logowanie" style="margin: auto; max-width: 180px; margin-top: 50px; ">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
                <thead></thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h:outputText value="login:" /></td>
                        <td><h:inputText value="#{loginBean.login}" size="10"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><h:outputText value="password:" /> </td>
                        <td><h:inputSecret value="#{login.password}" size="10"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><h:commandButton value="zaloguj" action="#{loginBean.login}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>

            </div>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

PANEL BEAN (the second bean)

```
package main;

import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="panelBean")
public class panelBean implements Serializable{

    private String login;
    private String password;
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    public panelBean()
    {
        loginBean Bean = (loginBean) context.getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(context, "loginBean");

        this.password = Bean.getPassword();
        this.login = Bean.getLogin();


        Bean.setPassword("");
        Bean.setLogin("");


        ExternalContext ectx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)ectx.getResponse();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession)ectx.getSession(false);
        session.invalidate();
    }

}
```

FACES CONFIG

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!-- =========== FULL CONFIGURATION FILE ================================== -->

<faces-config version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>yes</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/panel.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>no</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not create two sessions, but rather two session-scoped beans that live in the same session.

It might however be better if you make the bean that manages the login view-scoped, since there is not really a reason for it to be session-scoped (it is always advisable to keep session-state small). The `loginBean` would then simply set the state of the `panelBean`.

Comment: Thank you. Im using CGI therefore i've chosen request scope beacause viev scope is not supported